# If and else statments Java trying to stop a statement Homework

Tags: java, if-statement, clock, bluej

This is my code...

```
private void updateDisplay() {
    if(hours.getValue() == 0){
        hours.setValue(12);
        displayString = hours.getDisplayValue() + ":" + 
        minutes.getDisplayValue() + " am"; 
    }
    else if(hours.getValue() < 12){
        displayString = hours.getDisplayValue() + ":" + 
        minutes.getDisplayValue() + " am";
    }
    else if(hours.getValue() == 12){
        displayString = hours.getDisplayValue() + ":" + 
        minutes.getDisplayValue() + " pm";
    }
    else if(hours.getValue() < 24){ 
        displayString = hours.getValue() - 12 + ":" +  
        minutes.getDisplayValue() + " pm"; 
    }
}
```

So basically this is a clock im trying to display in 12 hour format.. When it changes from 11:59pm

i get it to say 12:00 am but once I timeTick() it once it goes 12:01 pm because of my if hours.getValue == 0 then we make it 12 but later in the method its if hours.getValue() ==  12 make it PM. I want to avoid that so. Any ideas on this while maintaining rather simple java?

RESOLVED Thank you. Instead of setValue(12) I just added 12 if hours.getValue() == 0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just do what you do for when the hours equals 12?

Don't actually set the hours value and just add 12 when you print it.

Comment: You're right i was already using it for the pm I dont know why I didnt see it for the am. Thanks alot dude

Answer (score 0):

use an 24hour clock internally, but display its value using "hours mod 12"

Comment: Im not familar with what you mean...And because its for an assignment I cant really go outside of what we were suppose to learn you know. You're right though internally it is a 24 hr , I just have to display it as a 12.. I can get past this 12:01. I set my value to 12 but next time i display it will see that 12 and take it for a pm which it wont be at this time...

Comment: `mod`is the rest of a division, and in Java is used with the `%`symbol. `4 % 3 = 1 ; 24 % 12 = 0`

Comment: Only problem is, 24h != 0am, but 12pm. Likewise for 12h. It needs additional handling (the way OP has it already).

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `hours.getValue()` returns an `int`, you can do `hours.getValue()/13 == 0 ? hours.getValue() + ":" + minutes.getDisplayValue() + " AM": hours.getValue() - 12 + ":" + minutes.getDisplayValue() + " PM";`. The expression is called the ternary operator and the int data type trims the decimal result.

I updated it to do everything. I hope you like 1 liners.